# The correct way of performing OneHotEncoding for neural network models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, keras, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset of multiclass (0,1,2) labels. Since I am using Keras, I need to first perform `OneHotEncoding` on the class column in the dataset using `keras.utils.to_categorical` method. Thus, I wonder which one of the following cases is correct:

Case 1 (perform `to_categorical` separately on train and test labels):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical

X, y = load_data(path)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
model.fit(x_train, to_categorical(y_train))
model.predict(x_test, to_categorical(y_test))
```

Case 2 (perform `to_categorical` before splitting):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical

X, y = load_data(path)
y = to_categorical(y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.predict(x_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to do it after splitting. It's not data-leakage. Also, you risk the case where you don't have samples from some of the classes in your test data. It happens in leave-one-out CV for example.